# Perlin Noise understanding

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, perlin-noise

I found two tutorials that explains how the Perlin Noise works, but in the first tutorial I found not understandable mystery of gradients, and in the second one I found the mystery of surflets.

**First case**

The first tutorial is located here [catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/noise](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/noise/). At first autor explains the value noise which is completely understandable, because all we need to do is to draw a grid of random colors and then just interpolate between the colors.

But when it comes to the Perlin Noise, we have to deal with gradients, not with single colors. At first I thought about gradiens as colors, so if we have two gradients and we want to make interpolation between them, we have to take a respective point of the first gradient and interpolate it with respective point of the second gradient. But if the gradients are the same, we will have a result which is the same as gradients.

In the tutorial author makes it in another way. If we have a 1d grid which consists of columns that are filled with the same gradient, and each gradient can be represented as transition from 0 to 1 (here 0 is black color, and 1 is white color). Then author says

> Now every stripe has the same gradient, except that they are offset
>   from one another. So for every t0, the gradient to the right of it is
>   t1 = t0 - 1. Let's smoothly interpolate them.

So it means that we have to interpolate between a gradient which is represented as transition from 0 to 1, and a gradient which is represented as transition from -1 to 0.

It implies that every gradient doesn't start at position with value of 0 and doesn't stop at position with value of 1. It starts somewhere at -1 and ends somewhere at 2, or maybe it has no start and end points. We can see only 0 to 1 range, and I can't understand why it is like this. Whence did we take the idea of continuous gradient? I thought that we have only gradient from 0 to 1 for every strip and that's all, don't we? [image: continuous gradient]

When I asked the author about all this he answered like this is something obvious

> The gradient to the right is a visual reference. It’s the gradient for
>   the next higher integer. You’re right that it goes negative to the
>   left. They all do.
>
> So t0 is the gradient that’s zero at the lattice point on the left
>   side of the region between two integers. And t1 is the gradient that’s
>   zero at the lattice point on the right side of the same region.
>   Gradient noise is obtained by interpolating between these two
>   gradients in between lattice points. And yes, that can produce
>   negative results, which end up black. That’s why the next step is to
>   scale and offset the result.

Now I feel like this is impossible for me to understand how this works, so I have just to believe and repeat after smarter guys. But hope dies last, so I beg you to explain it to me somehow.

**Second case**

The second tutorial is located here [eastfarthing.com/blog/2015-04-21-noise/](http://eastfarthing.com/blog/2015-04-21-noise/) and it's much less sophisticated than the previous one.
The only problem I had encountered is that I can't understand next paragraph and what's going on after this

> So given this, we can just focus on the direction of G and always use
>   unit length vectors. If we clamp the product of the falloff kernel and
>   the gradient to 0 at all points beyond the 2×2 square, this gives us
>   the surflet mentioned in that cryptic sentence.

I'm not sure whether the problem is in my poor math or English knowledge, so I ask you to explain what does this actually mean in simple words.

Here is some code I have written so far, it relates to the second case

```
import sys
import random
import math
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.gx=1
        self.gy=0
        self.lbl=QLabel()
        self.tlb = None
        self.image = QImage(512, 512, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.length = 1
        self.initUI()

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        px = QMouseEvent.pos().x()
        py = QMouseEvent.pos().y()

        size = self.frameSize()

        self.gx = px-size.width()/2
        self.gy = py-size.height()/2

        h = (self.gx**2+self.gy**2)**0.5

        self.gx/=h
        self.gy/=h

        self.fillImage()

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        self.length+=(event.delta()*0.001)
        print(self.length)


    def initUI(self):    
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.move(300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Red Rock')

        self.addedWidget = None

        self.fillImage()

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.show()  

    def fillImage(self):

        step = 128
        for x in range(0, 512, step):
            for y in range(0, 512, step):

                rn = random.randrange(0, 360)
                self.gx = math.cos(math.radians(rn))
                self.gy = math.sin(math.radians(rn))

                for x1 in range(0, step):

                    t = -1+(x1/step)*2
                    color =  (1 - (3 - 2*abs(t))*t**2) 

                    for y1 in range(0, step):

                        t1 = -1+(y1/step)*2
                        color1 = (1 - (3 - 2*abs(t1))*t1**2)
                        result = (255/2)+(color * color1 * (t*self.gx+t1*self.gy) )*(255/2)
                        self.image.setPixel(x+x1, y+y1, qRgb(result, result, result))


        self.pixmap = self.pixmap.fromImage(self.image)

        if self.lbl == None:
            self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        else:
            self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        if self.addedWidget == None:
            self.hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
            self.addedWidget = True

        self.repaint()
        self.update()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float Noise::perlin1D(glm::vec3 point, float frequency)
{
    // map the point to the frequency space
    point *= frequency;

    // get the base integer the point exists on
    int i0 = static_cast<int>(floorf(point.x));

    // distance from the left integer to the point
    float t0 = point.x - static_cast<float>(i0);

    // distance from the right integer to the point
    float t1 = t0 - 1.f;

    // make sure the base integer is in the range of the hash function
    i0 &= hashMask;

    // get the right integer (already in range of the hash function)
    int i1 = i0 + 1;

    // choose a pseudorandom gradient for the left and the right integers
    float g0 = gradients1D[hash[i0] & gradientsMask1D];
    float g1 = gradients1D[hash[i1] & gradientsMask1D];

    // take the dot product between our gradients and our distances to
    // get the influence values. (gradients are more influential the closer they are to the point)
    float v0 = g0 * t0;
    float v1 = g1 * t1;

    // map the point to a smooth curve with first and second derivatives of 0
    float t = smooth(t0);

    // interpolate our influence values along the smooth curve 
    return glm::mix(v0, v1, t) * 2.f;
}
```

here is a commented version of the code in question. But rewritten for c++. Obviously all credit goes to [catlikecoding](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/noise/).

We've given the function a point *p*. Let's assume the point *p* is fractional so for example if *p* is .25 then the integer to the left of *p* is 0 and the integer to the right of *p* is 1. Let's call these integers *l* and *r* respectively.

Then t0 is the distance from *l* to *p* and t1 is the distance from *r* to *p*. The distance is negative for t1 since you have to move in a negative direction to get from *r* to *p*.

If we continue on to the perlin noise part of this implementation g0 and g1 are pseudorandom gradients in 1 dimension. Once again gradient may be confusing here since g0 and g1 are floats, but a gradient is simply a direction and in one dimension you can only go positive or negative, so these gradients are +1 and -1. We take the dot product between the gradients and the distances, but in one dimension this is simply multiplication. The result of the dot product is the two floats v0 and v1. These are the influence values of our perlin noise implementation. Finally we smoothly interpolate between these influence values to produce a smooth noise function. Let me know if this helps! [This perlin noise explanation](http://flafla2.github.io/2014/08/09/perlinnoise.html) was very helpful in my understanding of this code.